# define path to a file in my google drive in a colab notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just starting with python and I'm trying to adapt a code from a colab notebook that is :

```
path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'cornell_movie_dialogs.zip',
    origin='http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~cristian/data/cornell_movie_dialogs_corpus.zip',
    extract=True)

path_to_dataset = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), "cornell movie-dialogs corpus")

path_to_movie_lines = os.path.join(path_to_dataset, 'movie_lines.txt')
path_to_movie_conversations = os.path.join(path_to_dataset,
                                           'movie_conversations.txt')
```

As I created a folder in my connected google drive with those files in it, I'm trying to point to those files instead of using the above code to download and extract a zip file.

I tried both the uncomment and the commented way:

```
path_to_dataset = 'drive/My Drive/fixit/data actual' 

path_to_movie_lines = os.path.join(path_to_dataset, 'movie_lines.txt')
path_to_movie_conversations = os.path.join(path_to_dataset, 'movie_conversations.txt')


# path_to_movie_lines = os.path.join('drive/My Drive/fixit/data actual','movie_lines.txt')

# path_to_movie_conversations = os.path.join('drive/My Drive/fixit/data actual','movie_conversations.txt')
```

but when I run the next bit of code I get the `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'drive/My Drive/fixit/data actual/movie_lines.txt'`.
What's the right way to access those files?
As always thank you very much.

```
def preprocess_sentence(sentence):
  sentence = sentence.lower().strip()
  # creating a space between a word and the punctuation following it
  # eg: "he is a boy." => "he is a boy ."
  sentence = re.sub(r"([?.!,])", r" \1 ", sentence)
  sentence = re.sub(r'[" "]+', " ", sentence)
  # replacing everything with space except (a-z, A-Z, ".", "?", "!", ",")
  sentence = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z?.!,]+", " ", sentence)
  sentence = sentence.strip()
  # adding a start and an end token to the sentence
  return sentence


def load_conversations():
  # dictionary of line id to text
  id2line = {}
  with open(path_to_movie_lines, errors='ignore') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
  for line in lines:
    parts = line.replace('\n', '').split(' +++$+++ ')
    id2line[parts[0]] = parts[4]

  inputs, outputs = [], []
  with open(path_to_movie_conversations, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
  for line in lines:
    parts = line.replace('\n', '').split(' +++$+++ ')
    # get conversation in a list of line ID
    conversation = [line[1:-1] for line in parts[3][1:-1].split(', ')]
    for i in range(len(conversation) - 1):
      inputs.append(preprocess_sentence(id2line[conversation[i]]))
      outputs.append(preprocess_sentence(id2line[conversation[i + 1]]))
      if len(inputs) >= MAX_SAMPLES:
        return inputs, outputs
  return inputs, outputs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't use the Google Drive's file directly from Colab. First, you have to run the code below in colab to mount Google Drive to Colab:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
%cd /gdrive
```

Then

```
%cd /gdrive/My Drive/fixit
%ls
%cp -r 'data actual' /content/sample_data
```

And change your path to dataset to this:

```
path_to_dataset = 'data actual'
```

Or maybe you don't need path_to_dataset anymore, just delete it, and change code to this:

```
path_to_movie_lines = 'movie_lines.txt' 
path_to_movie_conversations = 'movie_conversations.txt'
```

Just try delete path to dataset or not. One of this two ways will work.

In my old project, i don't use path to dataset, i just use dataset .txt files directly like they are in the same folder with my notebook.

P/S: Sory for my bad english.

Comment: Hi and first of all welcome to the community !
I actually mounted the drive and only `drive.mount('/content/drive')` will mount as `drive.mount('/content/drive/My Drive/fixit/data actual')`throws an error because of the space in `My Drive``

Comment: also the third way.. using PyDrive.. what's the point of connecting a google drive if you can't access the files in it in a easy way? You already have to authenticate to mount it.. isn't that enough?? I than rather go for uploading the files from a local drive..

Comment: @Vincenzo sory about that. I don't really remember how i mounted a specify folder in the past. So i think you can just use: 
    drive.mount('/content/drive')
And it will be fine.

Comment: `And now you can acess to folder "data actual" that contain "movie_lines.txt" and "movie_conversations.txt" normally.`
Can you give me a code example please? I'm miserably failing as in my examples

Comment: I don't know what it is, too. I have used Colab for about 5 months, and never touch it before. I think second method and the waymount Google Drive using authenticate code that i mention above are good enough.

Comment: Afer you mount Google drive, i think your path to dataset should be this: path_to_dataset = 'content/drive/My Drive/fixit/data actual'. because the "drive" folder is mounted in to Colab "content" folder.

Comment: @Vincenzo I just editted my first comment, please check it. It is the way that i used in my old project.

Comment: no actually is behaving strangely:


1. since I uploaded those two files directly and than delete them, it keep showing them with the `%ls` command.
2. the `%cd drive`command works ( not `gdrive`) ;) and shows `My Drive`and the two files.
3. the `%cd drive/My Drive`  throws a `No such directory `error, but `%cd My Drive` works fine and shows the sub folders correctly.
4. the `%cd My Drive/fixit` doesn't work and the `No such directory `error is thrown again.
4 the `%cd fixit` command doesn't either 
It seems that `My Drive is the deepest level I can get into..

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. I war tryng a lot of combinations..

Comment: Ok..this is crazy..

Now even `%cd drive` doesn't work anymore..

Comment: I think you should delete current notebook, and wait for a while then create new notebook.

Comment: Yep I'm thnking the same here ;)

Comment: Good luck to you. I am going to sleep, now. It is late in my country.

Comment: Thank your very much for your help so far

Comment: Thanks Thuat, the error was an empty space in folder's folder name.. 
`path_to_movie_lines = '/content/drive/My Drive/fixit/data actual/movie_lines.txt'` now works..
I'm so new to python that my worried brain didn't  think of a typo.
As for the weird behaving:
If you start changing directory and get errors as I was, just restart the runtime.
`shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Transport endpoint is not connected
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Transport endpoint is not connected`

Comment: So great information. Thank you so much. And I want to thank you for the accepted answer, too. It's my first accepted answer. I am so happy now.